# PIXI Check if DisplayObject is added to or removed from stage

Tags: dom, pixi.js

In PIXI is there a way to know if a `DisplayObject` is added to or removed from stage. I'm aware of the 'added' and 'removed' events, but they only trigger if the immediate `DisplayObject` is added to or removed from its parent but not recursively for all its parents.

I need this to toggle dom-elements on and off depending on the visibility of the overall `DisplayObject`.

Any advise or pointers on this are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking the attachment to stage and visibility manually on an interval. Advantage is that it's now also pretty easy to calculate the total alpha if I would ever need that.

```
private _handleInterval():void {
    let addToStage:boolean = false;
    let p:PIXI.DisplayObject = this; // 'this' is an extension of a PIXI.Container
    while (p != null && p.visible) {
        if (p.parent === this.stage) {
            addToStage = true;
            break;
        }
        p = p.parent;
    }
}
```

Not the most elegant solution since I would have preferred a pure Pixi solution but it gets the job done :)

If anyone has a better suggestion feel free to post a new answer!